# блокировка с намерением (intent lock)

Tags: база-данных

Немного не понял описание этого типа блокировки:

> Разделяемые и монопольные типы блокировок для таблицы соответствуют
>   одноименным блокировкам для строк и страниц. Обычно блокировка с
>   намерением (intent lock) означает, что транзакция намеревается
>   блокировать следующий нижележащий в иерархии объектов базы данных
>   ресурс. Таким образом, блокировка с намерением помещается на уровне
>   иерархии объектов, который выше того объекта, который этот процесс
>   намеревается заблокировать. Это является действенным способом узнать,
>   возможна ли подобная блокировка, а также устанавливается запрет другим
>   процессам блокировать более высокий уровень, прежде чем процесс может
>   установить требуемую ему блокировку.

Т.е ее смысл в том, что этот тип показывает, что транзакция может через какое-то время продолжить что-то еще блокировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блокировки Intent связаны с оптимизацией производительности.

Давайте рассмотрим это более подробно на примере MS SQL. С Intent Lock SQL Server просто указывает на более высокий уровень в иерархии блокировки, которую вы приобрели в другом месте. Intent Shared Lock сообщает SQL Server, что в другом месте есть Shared Lock. Update Intent или Intent Exclusive Lock делает то же самое, но на этот раз SQL Server знает, что есть блокировка обновления или эксклюзивная блокировка. Это всего лишь показатель, не более того.

Но как это указание помогает с оптимизацией производительности? Представьте, что вы хотите приобрести эксклюзивную блокировку на уровне таблицы. В этом случае SQL Server должен знать, есть ли несовместимая блокировка (например, Shared или Update Lock) где-то еще в записи. Без блокировок Intent SQL Server должен будет проверить каждую запись, чтобы узнать, предоставлена ли несовместимая блокировка.

Но с помощью блокировки Intent Shared Lock на уровне таблицы SQL Server сразу знает, что Shared Lock был предоставлен где-то в другом месте, и поэтому исключающая блокировка не может быть предоставлена на уровне таблицы.

Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос.

Источник: [Why do we need Intent Locks in SQL Server?](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/05/16/why-do-we-need-intent-locks-in-sql-server/)